# Cassandra, read value of column type map<> using ByteBufferUtil (org.apache.cassandra.utils)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, bytebuffer

I'm developing have Hadoop running on top of Cassandra. It's all running very well, but I have now bumped into a problem I can't find the solution to.

One of my columns contains a collection, definition is something similar to:

`create table productUsage(
    ....
    products map,
    productcategories map
)...` 

etc.

In my map/reduce map function, I need to read the values from these columns, but can't work out how to convert the column data - which is a byte buffer - into the a usable HashMap variable - the ByteBufferUtil function doesn't seem to help.

The map/reduce map code I have that extracts the column values at the moment looks like this...

string productid;
HashMap products;

for (Entry column : columns.entrySet()){

```
  if ("productid".equalsIgnoreCase(column.getKey())){
      productid = ByteBufferUtil.string(column.getValue());
  }

  if ("products".equalsIgnoreCase(column.getKey())){
      products = ???? //ByteBufferUtil.string(column.getValue());
  }
```

}

Does anyone have any idea's or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Gerry

Comment: Sorry, yes I should have mention, Apache Cassandra 1.2.6

Comment: Have you tried ``MapType.getInstance(K-type,V-Type).compose(column.getValues())``

Where K-Type and V-Type are instances of classes or key and value (for example ``Int32Type.instance``, ``UTF8Type.instance`` etc)

Comment: Hi Mikhail, no I hadn't tried that, but have now and it was exactly what I was after. Works perfectly! Thank you so much for that, i've been hunting for that for ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave it as an answer then.
Use `MapType.getInstance(K-type,V-Type).compose(column.getValues())` Where `K-Type` and `V-Type` are instances of classes for key and value (for example `Int32Type.instance`, `UTF8Type.instance` etc)